# Updating values on page without refreshing in Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I am trying to update values on my page when I user selects what they want to filter but I do not want to refresh the webpage constantly. As an example, think of a real estate website where you filter based on location and the types of housing come back with the number (e.g., apartment [4] townhouse [0] studio [5]). The types of housing will always be there but its the numbers I am interested in updating. When ever you change the filter, new numbers are popping up. What I am doing is filtering questions based on topic, subject etc.

Is there anyway to use this in node.js? What I have working so far requires the page to refresh.

```
$.ajax({
    type="POST",
    url: "/user/calculatequestions",
    data: { 
         filter date here... },
    success: function () { },
    error: function () { }
});
```

The '/user/calculatequestions' goes through an app.post and renders a new page with new variables.

Thanks in advance,
S

Comment: why invoke a post if the user is only changing drop-downs et al? you should add an event-listener to your filter elements and when they click [apply], then you can invoke your ajax func.

Comment: thanks for the response. ideally I want the values to be updated as the user changes the checkboxes (i.e., filter) and I do not want to invoke a post. I just want to get something working and now am polishing it up a bit. My question is how do I send send filters to node and have node send back some numbers without having the refresh/post the page.

Comment: nothing in ajax code shown would refresh the page. Queston doesn't make sense

Comment: Sorry. Please bear with me. I am using ajax to communicate with the server. The server does a res.render which refreshes the page. My question is **how would you send back data from node.js to the webpage without refreshing the webpage** so I could update the values. I used res.render because that was the only way I could think of in my limited experience to get something working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the values of the filter through Java Script and send data filter through Ajax.

Example of input:

```
    <input id="field" name="field1" type="text" >
```

Java Script function (together Ajax stack):

```
    var data = {};
    data.fielter_data1 = document.getElementById('field');

    $.ajax({
        type="POST",
        url: "/user/calculatequestions",
        data: data,
        success: function () { },
        error: function () { }
    });
```

Then, in the function node called /user/calculatequestion you can get the parameters filter with:

```
var filter_data = req.body.fielter_data1;
```

The **success** callback returns the data after note proccess, then you update the components (inputs, tables, lists and etc) in the front-end.

See this question please: [How to refresh table data using Ajax, Json and Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025833/how-to-refresh-table-data-using-ajax-json-and-node-js)

Comment: Thanks. The key to the answer to my question was the res.send(data) which would appear in success: function(data) { ... }.

Comment: wait, aren't you missing Content Type in ur ajax call??

Comment: My code did not work until I added   contentType: 'application/json'

Comment: Hi @LukaGabadze, maybe on the time that I aswered the question, the jQuery version did not required application time, but now on the version that you are using, it is.